# No proxy flag for cabal under windows?

Tags: haskell, proxy, cabal

When I try to run cabal behind a proxy without setting `HTTP_PROXY`, I get

```
C:\Users\joeschmo>cabal update
Downloading the latest package list from hackage.haskell.org
cabal: openTCPConnection: host lookup failure for "hackage.haskell.org"
```

---

`cabal -h` doesn't give a proxy option, and I can't find any info on how to set up a .cabal file to remediate this either.

For security reasons setting the `HTTP_PROXY` environment var is probably a bad idea.

Any ideas? Trying to find a solution other than at the command line:

```
set HTTP_PROXY=http://username:password@proxyurl:port
```

Comment: I haven't been able to find anything about this either, I've always had to set `HTTP_PROXY`.

Answer (score 0):

Proxy can be configured in `~/.cabal/config`. Add this line to the config file:

```
export http_proxy=http://${username}:${password}@${proxy_address}:${port}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure it can't be.

Answer (score 0):

Modern `cabal-install` lets you set an `http-transport` either at the command line or in the `.cabal/config` file. If you set this transport to `curl` or `wget`, etc then you can use whatever mechanisms you use to give *them* a proxy to give your proxy to `cabal`.